# Symfony 3 logout doesn't work

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, logout

I have very strange problem which makes me mad.
On local machine logout works as expected, but when I try logout on development server it doesn't logout me from the application. Can somebody can help me or explain why this issue might occurs?
On server and local machine there are different PHP versions (on local machine php 5.6 and php7 on development server), this the single difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was caused due to enabled AppCache.
After disabling it - everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Disabled `AppCache` and everything works now! But this strange issue, that `AppCache` brakes work of FOS bundle